# bash read mystery: `read -d'' -s -n 1` eats hyphens

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use the `read` builtin in `bash` to read one character at a time.  This actually works flawlessly when I use the `-N 1` argument to `read`, but I had some OSX users report to me that their bash does not have that option.

So now I'm using something along the lines of:

```
$ while IFS= read -r -d'' -s -n 1 char; do echo -n "${char}"; done < filename
```

This echo's back every character in `filename` one at a time *except*, mysteriously, hyphens (`-`).  E.g. if I have

```
$ cat blah
uh-oh
```

The result is:

```
$ while IFS= read -r -d'' -s -n 1 char; do echo -n "${char}"; done < blah
uhoh
```

Nothing in the documentation says anything that would indicate this.  If I replace `${char}` in the `echo` with `${#char}` it prints `0` where it should have read the hyphen.  It just gets completely eaten.

If I drop the `-d''` it instead eats newlines, but does *not* eat hyphen, so that at least makes sense since newline is the default delimiter.  It almost seems like a bug that `-d''` is treating hyphen as a delimiter.

FWIW I have

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(4)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)
```

but this was first reported to me by an OSX user.

Comment: Use `printf %s "$char"` instead of (non-standard) `echo -n "$char"`...

Comment: Is using `printf` really more portable than `echo -n`?

Comment: Yes. POSIX `echo` does not specify any standard for `-n`.

Comment: According to the [single unix specification v3 for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html), "If the first operand is -n, or if any of the operands contain a backslash ( '\' ) character, the results are implementation-defined." See [this answer by Stéphane Chazelas](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) and his link to [Sven Mascheck's catalog of incompatibility](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/echo+printf/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually did not set the *delimiter* option for read correctly.

Notice the extra space:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' -s -n 1 char; do echo -n "${char}"; done < filename
```

This works fine.
In your code the *delimiter* chars where set to `-s`

Comment: Amazing, and subtle.  Thank you!  (I think the lack of space was force of habit from `cut` whose delimiter option doesn't need a space before the delimiter itself).

Comment: What's further baffling is that the `-s` is still processed correctly too.

Comment: Actually `-s` isn't processed. The option is only meaningful if `stdin` is a terminal. Because you used redirection the input isn't echoed anyway

Comment: Right, but that's still strange--in the example I have I was reading from a file, but the actual code *is* reading from a terminal and `-s` was working as expected.

Comment: Nevermind, when I try the above example with `-d''` it is clearly not processing the `-s` as you say.  Which is odd because in my actual script it was definitely not echoing each character input twice.  Not sure what that's about.